# HTTPS issue with apache batik PNGTranscoder

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, https, batik

I'm currently facing an issue in Apache Batik 1.7 where I'm trying to convert an SVG to PNG using PNGTranscoder class.

The SVG element has images in it, which batik tries to fetch via HTTP calls.
An exception is thrown while fetching those images as follows:

```
org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException: null
Enclosed Exception:
null:0
The URI "https://sdp-w8-4:8080/custom/customimages/technicians_citype.png"
on element <image> can't be opened because:
The URI can't be opened:
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.ImageTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
```

I can see that the issue is that certificate is not found, but I can't figure out what I'm missing!

The server has configured https and I can access it via the browser, and this batik code is running in the same server itself.

Do I have to specify the certificate separately for batik? If so, how can I do it? The server is tomcat.

I have not specified anything related to security for batik, and this is my code for export.

```
TranscoderInput transcoderInput = new TranscoderInput(processedInputStream);
        TranscoderOutput transcoderOutput = new TranscoderOutput(resultByteStream);

        PNGTranscoder pngTranscoder = new PNGTranscoder();
        pngTranscoder.addTranscodingHint(ImageTranscoder.KEY_ALTERNATE_STYLESHEET, "/svgrelationshipmap.css"); //no i18n
        pngTranscoder.addTranscodingHint(ImageTranscoder.KEY_BACKGROUND_COLOR, Color.white);

        pngTranscoder.transcode(transcoderInput, transcoderOutput);
```

processedInputStream and resultByteStream are two byte streams. ProcessedByteStream has the svg data.

The process works fine in HTTP, hence, proving that the SVG is correct.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Usually this is because of a self signed certificate on the server.  By default Java doesn't accept these.  Can you show more code to show where you opened the `processedInputStream`?

Comment: @tdunbar I narrowed it down to the same, is there a way to make java accept them?

Comment: @stdunbar The code for processsedInputStream is a little bit complicated, hence can't post here without making a mess of the question. Basically, I pass the dom data of svg as string to server, from where I parse it into a document and then open a stream from that.